# SPA with links of suffix .html , is it possible?

Tags: html, responsive-design, react-router, single-page-application

I have a static web server web site, let say , host on AWS S3.
Now, it is an old html4 multi page site, it contains lot of html files in different folders,
eg.
1. www.hello.com/welcome.html
2. www.hello.com/en/publication.html
3. www.hello.com/sc/publication.html
...etc
We plan to rewrite the site to html5, so it can be RWD ready.
We like to retain the path pattern, so anyone have bookmark our page can still go to the page.
We consider rewrite the site in SPA framework too. We have learn the react-router, in their example, the  contain path something like this
www.hello.com/en/publication
Can I rewrite the site by SPA framwork, eg. react-router. using the link path with .html suffix. But actually it is a SPA run on a single index.html.
Note: we don't want to upgrade server from static to application server.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your revamped SPA site in S3 and serve through CloudFront. However, I see that you need to have some fallback some URLs for previous bookmarks and maybe also for SEO reasons.

This you can achieve using a [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function which will be able to route traffic as required and also serve the Single Page Application index.html for the frontend routes.